# Interpreting moderated quadratic effect in mixed effect models

Tags: mixed-model, model-selection, quadratic-form

I study the effect of the same stimulus ($X$), displaced in 4 different conditions (categorical $M$, categories=High, Medium, Low, in addition there is "Control" condition, as a reference level) on participants. The variable $Y$ is measured for the whole time. Since $Y$ is repeatedly measured, I decided to introduce time as a variable, and observe how $Y$ changes overtime, and whether the way it changes varies from one condition to another (basically, whether $M$ moderates the change of $Y$). A quick plot indicates that there may be nonlinearity in the way $Y$ changes, mostly U-shape. Upon comparison (informed by AIC), I conclude that the following model performs the best:

```
model1<-lmer(data=data, formula = Y~M*Time_quadratic+Time_linear+(1+Time_linear|ID)
, REML = FALSE)
```

And the summary of the model shows:
[image]

Update: per Robert's suggestion, I centered the Time variable before introducing its quadratic term and interaction terms. Here's the updated result from the model -- it did improved slightly.

[image]

Background: I know that positive coefficient for Time_quadratic means the data is U-shape, while a negative coefficient indicates inverted U-shape. However, I am not entirely sure how to interpret the coefficient for the interaction term.

Questions:
For example, `M_High:Time_quadratic` has a coefficient of -4.855e-05. Does that mean the data in the High condition is inverted U-shape, or it is still U-shape, but -4.855e-05 less U-shape than the control, given the Control condition is the reference level?

A smaller coefficient in quadratic effect means a larger parabola. That means, compared with the "Control“ condition, the high, low, and medium conditions all have larger parabolas, thus flatter U-shape curves, which is supported by visualization. Note: I'm modeling data in T2. Red=Control, Blue =Low, Green=High, Violet=Medium

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Before including quadratic time terms in your model it is good to centre the linear term to avoid high correlation with the quadratic term. Also, before fitting interactions with the quadratic term, did you fit interactions with the linear term, and if so why did you exclude those when you added the quadratic interactions ? If not, why did you go straight to interactions with the quadratic term ?

Comment: @Robert I did include interaction with both the linear term and quadratic term in my first model, and compared it with the current model. AIC suggests I do significantly better without the linear term, that's why in the current model it is excluded.

Comment: Ok, but is time centred ? How many subjects do you have ?

Comment: @RobertLong Hi Robert, yes, thank you for the suggestion. I have now included in the post the model results in which Time has been centered (Time_linear_c) before introducing the quadratic term and interactions. AIC still suggests that I do better when only the interaction with the quadratic term is included.

Comment: Ok. I agree with your interpretation, but some of the estimates sizes are very small. Are those effect sizes meaningful in the context of your study ? I am guessing you have a large sample size and the study may be overpowered (which is fine but you just need to be careful not to report things that are statistically significant but practically meaningless)

Comment: @RobertLong Thanks! The interaction will not be a major part of the study but rather something to mention in the discussion, at least that's the plan for now. I also noticed that the overall nonlinear effect is small to start with, it seems my treatment groups have suppressed such effects by 30- 40% , which I believe worths some discussion.

Comment: @RobertLong Hi Robert, thanks again! We are running a study with 78 subjects in total, assigned to 3 treatment groups and 1 control group, so I am not terribly concerned by the possibility of being overpowered.